# While loop and mysql_fetch_assoc on one query?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I have a webpage that does a MySQL query on a table. I have it to echo it out in a table and that works as it should, example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query){
   // my table and db stuff echos out here
}
```

Now using the same mysql query **$query** I am trying to echo it out again on the same page using the same query underneath but my problem is it does not seem to work.

Now you maybe thinking what I'm doing is odd, but the reason why is the first code above echoes data out in a table, but also checkboxes next to the stuff echoed out as it is for a form. All that works fine but it seems I cannot do another while loop above on the same query. The second one is exactly the same as above; only difference is it's not a form.

Can I only do a `while()` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` once on a single query?

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry I still don't understand properly.

Here's my code; could anyone edit it for me?

(I could not put php tags in the code to split up the HTML from the PHP code. Sorry for any inconvenience).

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

<h1> Vote for your favourite extension </h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo basename(__file__); ?>">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td colspan="3" class="cellfeat" style="text-align: center;">Vote for your favourite extension</td>
    </tr>
        <?php
        if(!$q){
            // query failed etc

        } else { // query ok so display form
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
                echo '<tr class="odd">';
                echo '<td class="cellfeat"><img src="images/statimages/extensions.gif" alt="Extension Vote Image" /></td>';
                echo '<td class="cellfeat">'.$row['checkbox'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="cellfeat"><input type="checkbox" name="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'" /></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" class="submitcontact" value="Vote" />
</form>

<h1>Extension Statistics</h1>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td colspan="3" class="cellfeat" style="text-align: center;">Voting Statistics</td>
    </tr>
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
                echo '<tr class="odd">';
                echo '<td class="cellfeat"><img src="images/statimages/extensions.gif" alt="Extension Vote Image" /></td>';
                echo '<td class="cellfeat">'.$row['checkbox'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="cellfeat">'.$row['count'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: oh. your code is all wrong. where did you get it? do you have working code yet?

Comment: It's solved now thanks; and it was working fine just not on second query. but i used mysql_data_seek() and it does what i wanted. thanks phplover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you need to use this function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

to move your pointer

Comment: rulex ; i updated first post for assistance. Thanks for any help. phplover

Comment: rulex thanks, i managed to work it out afterwards. It looked more complicated than it was on the php manual. phplover :)

Comment: This is not a good approach. Fetching all data into an array is much more sensible.

Answer (score 9):

The only proper way as follows:
first, collect your data into array

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query){
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

then, **call a template**
and use your data as many times as you wish:

```
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row['id']?></td>
<td><?=$row['name']?></td>
<? endforeach ?>
</table?>
```

Comment: i updated first post for assistance. Thanks for any help. phplover

Comment: @PHPLOVER sorry, I do not edit codes. I believe  this site is dedicated to education, not charity.

Comment: It is about education but sometimes if we don't understand something i think it's a good thing to ask as we can examine changes to the code so we can learn from our mistakes / misunderstanding(s). I never ask for someone to alter my code unless i have tried all ways possible first. But thanks anyway i understand we hall have different oppionions. phplover

Comment: @PHPLOVER It least you have to ask to alter a working code, not one throwing parse errors right and left.